# Simple Algebra Question - Check My Simplification

Tags: limits

I know this process is incorrect, but where am I going wrong, and what do I need to learn to fix my erroneous thought process?

$$\frac{(25 - x)(\sqrt x + 5)}{x - 25}$$
$$ = \frac{25 - x}{x - 25} \cdot \sqrt x + 5 $$
$$ = \frac{25 - x}{-25+x} \cdot \sqrt x + 5 $$
$$ = \frac{25 - x}{-1 \cdot (25-x)} \cdot \sqrt x + 5 $$
$$ = \require{enclose} -1 \cdot \frac{25 - x}{25-x} \cdot \sqrt x + 5 $$
$$ = \require{enclose} -1 \cdot \sqrt x + 5 $$
$$ = -\sqrt x -5 $$

Comment: $$\frac{(25 - x)(\sqrt x + 5)}{x - 25}$$
$$ = \frac{25 - x}{x - 25}( \sqrt x + 5) $$
$$ = \frac{25 - x}{-25+x} ( \sqrt x + 5) $$
$$ = \frac{25 - x}{-1 \cdot (25-x)}( \sqrt x + 5) $$
$$ = \require{enclose} -1 \cdot \frac{25 - x}{25-x} (\sqrt x + 5) $$
$$ = \require{enclose} -1 (\sqrt x + 5) $$
$$ = -\sqrt x -5 $$

Comment: The only thing that looks incorrect here is that you're missing parentheses around the $\sqrt x+5$ that you took down from the fraction bar.

Comment: Maybe, depending on how much detail is expected, you could shorten things greatly by observing directly that $\frac{25-x}{x-25}=-1$ (if $x\ne 25$).

Comment: Besides the (correct) remarks above: note that the ineuqality really only holds when $x\neq 25$, as @AndréNicolas mentioned. Otherwise, the end result is defined, but *not* he original expression.

Comment: I think you know what you are doing and are getting the right answer but on the second line you *must* write "$\sqrt x +5" inside parenthesis. To indicate that when you multiply  you distribute to *both* terms. What you wrote means to only multiply $\sqrt x $ and not to multiply the 5. I expected you to make error when you reduced to -1 that you'd only multiply the $\sqrt x$ by -1 and not the 5.  But you didn't make the mistake: you correctly multiplied the 5 by -1.  So you got the right answer.  But for lines 2 thru 6 you wrote everything wrong by not writing "($\sqrt x +5$)" in parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone. It was the missing parentheses that were throwing me off. And to the people who mentioned that the formula only works when x doesn't equal 25 I understand that. This problem was actually part of a solution to a limit.